# WSO2 ESB axis2 xml message builders

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, wso2-esb

In the axis2.xml of wso2esb there are something called messagebuilders and messageformatters. I don't understand understand what those are for?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this](http://wso2.com/library/articles/axis2-configuration-part2-learning-axis2-xml/) resource to find out information on Message Builders and formatters.

Comment: Please add detailed answer also as the link might go down in future.